# How to run a program right after user logon on win8?

Tags: windows, authentication, operating-system

As all know, Win8's windows logon sound setting does't work, so I decided to run a program to play a welcome sound right after user logon.
I write a vbs file, and I added it in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.
It works, but I still have to wait a few seconds to listen the welcome music after user logon. I think that might be because my vbs file doesn't run immediately after user logon, it might have to wait other programs that are also listed on startup menu before starting.
Could you help me?
(I know my english is so bad, I hope you can understand what I say (●'◡'●) )

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/416182/control-startup-sequence-of-startup-programs-in-windows

Comment: thanks.I have found this page in google results and have read it before post this question,but I don't think it has any help to me.